# Ioniczip packed files gets corrupted and filenames missplaced

Tags: c#, regex, zip

Im having some trouble with IonicZip corrupting the files im packing down with it. At first i thought it was because of the file names, but i have now discovered that this is not the case. 
Heres the code i use to pack down things

```
        using (ZipFile pack = new ZipFile())
        {
            pack.AddProgress += (s, eventArgs) =>
            {
                if (eventArgs.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Adding_AfterAddEntry)
                {
                    Regex pattern = new Regex("[(]|[)]|[']|[[]|[]]|[+]");
                    eventArgs.CurrentEntry.FileName = pattern.Replace(eventArgs.CurrentEntry.FileName, "");
                }
            };
            pack.AddDirectory(defPackageCreationPath + "\\installfiles", "");            
            pack.Save(outputPath + "\\package.mpp");
        }
```

I used Regex to remove the shown characters from the filenames of the files being packed, as i thought it was because of the filenames they got corrupted somehow. But it is not.

Heres an example. I can pack down this file without problems

```
[Forge]FurnitureModv2.9.2(FULL).zip
```

However! If i pack the same file down with a lot of other files, everything screws up..

Take a look at this screenshot of the source folder, where im taking the files from and packing them with the above code, and the extracted folder to the right:

[image: Left: Source, Right: Extracted]

Notice how the file sizes from the source directory doesn't match with what is extracted? Well take a look at the sizes again.. The filenames are not matching those of the source! The file i mentioned before [Forge]FurnitureModv2.9.2(FULL).zip, which is now called ForgeFurnitureModv2.9.2FULL.zip and has gone from 467KB down to 51KB, and if i try to open it, im being told it is corrupted.. But take a look at the TooMuchTNT v2.5.zip file.. This files size is 467KB as the other file was from source, and if i open this file up i get the contents that should have been in [Forge]FurnitureModv2.9.2(FULL).zip !

So all in all i have two problems:

1. being that the file names doesnt match their contents from source folder
2. some files gets corrupted, however if i pack a file that gets corrupted without any other file it works fine, and it does not get corrupted.

Can you assist ? Maybe im packing the files wrongly ?

Comment: Just curious, what's in TooMuchTNT v2.5.zip ???

Comment: The extracted file TooMuchTNT v2.5.zip has the same contents as the source file [Forge]FurnitureModv2.9.2(FULL).zip.. And the source file ForgeFurnitureModv2.9.2FULL.zip is corrupted.